# How to set popup after customer login

Tags: magento, popupwindow

I need popup with custom content after customer successfully login.

In content I need to set customer name, customer group and some other text.

Comment: where do you want to show popup ? (customer account dashboard or somewhere else ) ? generally we define observer for the event `customer_login` and do some logic inside. Depending on your requirement, you may need to override `Mage_Customer_AccountController`

Comment: Thanx @LaxmanSingh ....I have manage with success message set in controller redirection method so it's automatic set, because i have used intenso theme so......

Answer (score 0):

Use the event `customer_login`

```
<customer_login>
    <observers>
        <yourobservername>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
            <method>customerLogin</method>
        </yourobservername>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
```

Your observer class would look like this and you can call here your popup `.phtml` file

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Sunny ....I have manage with success message set in controller redirection method so it's automatic set, because i have used intenso theme so......

Comment: @Dhrumin I hope that you have not change in core controller. This is fine. You welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to work on events and observers in magento.

- First you will need to observe **customer_login** event and set some custom value in session.
- Next you will need to observe event like **controller_action_layout_load_before** or **controller_front_init_before**. In this observer function you will need to check value of session which you had set in previous step. If value is found then use code like:

`$layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
$layout->addHandle('some_handle')->removeHandle('some_other_handle');`

and after setting layout handle, you will need to unset session value which you had set in first step.
Please try to implement it and let me know if you find any problem.